# Leaflet - refresh GeoJSON layer from API using BBox of the map extents

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I'm trying to add a GeoJSON layer from an [OGCAPI-Features endpoint](https://ogcapi.bgs.ac.uk/collections/agsboreholeindex/items).

The layer has >59k features so I'm using a `limit=100` but I need the map to refresh the GeoJSON based on the map extent as the user pans/zoom around the map.

I've made a start and uit loads the first 100 features but it doesn't refresh as required.

Any suggestions?

```
(async () => {
    const agsboreholes = await fetch('https://ogcapi.bgs.ac.uk/collections/agsboreholeindex/items?bbox=' + map.getBounds().toBBoxString() + '&limit=100', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/geo+json'
      }
    }).then(response => response.json());
    L.geoJSON(agsboreholes, {
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
})();    

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var popupContent = "<b>AGS Borehole Information</b><br><hr>" +
            "<b>BGS LOCA ID: </b>" + feature.properties.bgs_loca_id + "<br>" +
            "<b>Depth (m): </b>" + feature.properties.loca_fdep + "<br>" +
            "<b>Project Name: </b>" + feature.properties.proj_name + "<br>" +
            "<b>Project Engineer: </b>" + feature.properties.proj_eng + "<br>" +
            "<b>Project Contractor: </b>" + feature.properties.proj_cont + "<br>" +
            "<b>Original LOCA ID: </b>" + feature.properties.loca_id + "<br>" +
            "<b>AGS Graphical Log: </b>" + "<a href=" + "https://agsapi.bgs.ac.uk/ags_log/?bgs_loca_id=" + feature.properties.bgs_loca_id + " target=" + "_blank" + ">View</a>" + "<br>" +
            "<b>AGS Data: </b>" + "<a href=" + "https://agsapi.bgs.ac.uk/ags_export/?bgs_loca_id=" + feature.properties.bgs_loca_id + " target=" + "_blank" + ">Download</a>" + "<br>" +
            "<b>AGS Submission Record (raw data): </b>" + "<a href=" + feature.properties.dad_item_url + " target=" + "_blank" + ">View</a>" + "<br>";
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
        popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
    }
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
}
```

Comment: The obvious answer would be https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/leaflet.featuregroup.ogcapi , but you're already aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided on GitLab

"I used

```
var l_ogc = L.featureGroup.ogcApi(url, { collection: 'kreise', pane: 'overlays', limit: 400 }); l_ogc.on("ready", () => {map.addLayer(l_ogc);})
```

to fix the race and read more than 100 features."

https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/leaflet.featuregroup.ogcapi/-/issues/2#note_1382843053